# Vectorizing a for loop in Python that includes a cumsum() and iterative slicing

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, cumulative-sum, minimum

I have the following for loop that operates over three numpy arrays of the same length:

```
n = 100
a = np.random.random(n)
b = np.random.random(n)
c = np.random.random(n)

valid = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    valid[i] = np.any(a[i] > b[i:] + c[i:].cumsum())
```

Is there a way to replace this for loop with some vectorized numpy operations?

For example, because I only care if `a[i]` is larger than any value in `b[i:]`, I can do `np.minimum.accumulate(b[::-1])[::-1]` which gets the smallest value of `b` at every index and onwards, and then compare it to `a` like this:

```
a > np.minimum.accumulate(b[::-1])[::-1]
```

but I still would need a way to vectorize the `c[i:].cumsum()` into a single array calculation.

Comment: I don't think the cumsum can be vectored out. But you could speed it up a littel with list comprehension: `valid = np.array([np.any(a[i] > b[i:] + c[i:].cumsum()) for i in range(n)])`

Comment: @Nathan. Of course you can

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't see an answer to upvote ;)

Comment: @Nathan. Was AFK. Will post one in 5

Comment: @Nathan. Posted now. Enjoy

Comment: @MadPhysicist does this technically count as vectorising? Still a good answer tho

Comment: @Nathan, "vectorizing" in common `numpy` usage means using compiled `numpy` methods to replace Python level iterations.  Often that involves making a larger temporary array (with `broadcasting` etc), followed by some sort of `reduction`.  In effect it moves iterations from interpreted python to compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to find the minimum of `b[i:] + c[i:].cumsum()` for each `i`. Clearly you can compare that to `a` directly.

You can write the elements of `c[i:].cumsum()` as the upper triangle of a matrix. Let's look at a toy case with `n = 3`:

```
c = [c1, c2, c3]
s1 = c.cumsum()
s0 = np.r_[0, s1[:-1]]
```

You can write the elements of the cumulative sum as

```
c1, c1 + c2, c1 + c2 + c3     s1[0:]                 s1[0:] - s0[0]
         c2,      c2 + c3  =  s1[1:] - c1         =  s1[1:] - s0[1]
                       c3     s1[2:] - (c1 + c2)     s1[2:] - s0[2]
```

You can use [`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to construct these sums as a raveled array:

```
r, c = np.triu_indices(n)
diff = s1[c] - s0[r] + b[c]
```

Since [`np.minimum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) is a [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.html), you can accumulate `diff` for each run defined by `r` using [`minimum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). The locations are given roughly by `np.flatnonzero(np.diff(r)) + 1`, but you can generate them faster with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
m = np.minimum.reduceat(diff, np.r_[0, np.arange(n, 1, -1).cumsum()])
```

So finally, you have:

```
valid = a > m
```

**TL;DR**

```
s1 = c.cumsum()
s0 = np.r_[0, s1[:-1]]
r, c = np.triu_indices(n)
valid = a > np.minimum.reduceat(s1[c] - s0[r] + b[c], np.r_[0, np.arange(n, 1, -1).cumsum()])
```

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling this would require a two dimensional approach due to the way `c[i:].cumsum()` produces a triangle, but I didn't think to use `reduceat`. Nice solution!

Comment: @trevor-pope. Yup. This was a fun one. I'm finding myself using `triu_indices` a lot recently for some reason, and of course reduceat comes naturally after.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to vectorize it to decrease the running time. Since you are only using pure NumPy operations, you can use `numba`: see [5 Minutes Guide to Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html)

it will look something like this:

```py
import numba

@numba.njit()
def valid_for_single_idx(idx, a, b, c):
    return np.any(a[idx] > b[idx:] + c[idx:].cumsum())


valid = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    valid[i] = valid_for_single_idx(i, a, b, c)
```

So far it isn't really vectorization (as the loop still happens), but it translate the the numpy line into llvm, so it happens as fast as probably possible.

Although it's not increasing the speed, but looks a bit nicer, you can use `.map`:

```py
import numba
from functools import partial

@numba.njit()
def valid_for_single_idx(idx, a, b, c):
    return np.any(a[idx] > b[idx:] + c[idx:].cumsum())


valid = map(partial(valid_for_single_idx, a=a, b=b, c=c), range(n))
```

Comment: `map` is unlikely to increase your speed unless you numba that too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist good point, I edited my  answer